# Showing that no two primes subtracted can give 97

Tags: prime-numbers

I want to prove that the it is not possible that when two prime numbers are subtracted, for them to result in 97:
$$p-q=97$$

But honestly, I don't know how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What can you say about two numbers whose difference is odd?

Comment: Ohh, that one of them is odd and one even, so both numbers cannot be prime! Thank you!

Comment: Well, it would have worked with a difference of 95.  Or 99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that all primes are odd except for $2$. If $p$ and $q$ are both odd, then the difference would be even, so it can't be $97$. Therefore, one of $p$ or $q$ must be $2$. If $p$ is $2$, then the difference would be negative. If $q$ was $2$, then $p$ would have to be $99$, which is not prime. Therefore, it is not possible.